# How to free memories in the heap without getting memory leak in linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, malloc, singly-linked-list

I wrote a function that will handle free of memory in linked list but the function was able to free them but i was getting memory leak. Please could someone tell me why this function was able to free my memory but there is memory leak.

```
void free_listint(listint_t *head)
{
    listint_t *temp;
     
    temp = head;
    while (head != NULL)
    {
         free(head);
         temp = temp->next;
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: `while (head != NULL)`? Where inside the loop do you make `head` point somewhere else? You have an infinite loop, and the list will run out, and you will dereference the null pointer. That leads to *undefined behavior* and a likely crash.

Comment: Your head is never moved inside the loop.

Comment: Ooh thanks. @Karthick i was thinking that my head pointer is meant to point to the first node while the second pointer loops through the list. Because the head pointer points to the address of the first node which should not be reassigned to avoid losing the address while the second pointer stores the temporary address.

Comment: Right. ```should not be reassigned to avoid losing the address``` is not applicable in this function because you are going to delete the entire list.

Answer (score 3):

Your while loop checks for head but head is never reassigned inside the loop. This might cause infinite loop and `temp = temp->next;` might eventually crash.

I would suggest to rewrite like

```
void free_listint(listint_t *head)
{
    listint_t *temp;
     
    while (head != NULL)
    {
         temp = head->next;
         free(head);
         head = temp;
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@Karthick shows the OP's error and one solution. (credit!)

For the fun of it, the following may *scan* slightly easier:

```
void free_listint( listint_t *head )
{
    while( head )
    {
        // strive to limit the scope of variables
        listint_t *del = head;
        head = head->next;
        free( del );
    }
    // return; // this is unnecessary. write less code.
}
```